# need javascript array format

Tags: javascript

I am looking to create following format in array in javascript.

Each item has:

- url -> string (which is login URL)
- name -> string
- inputs -> array

And each input is:

- name -> string
- type -> string
- value -> string

Please guide me , how to do this in JavaScript

Comment: google for "javascript object array literal"

Comment: could you clarify your question a bit, by specifying a couple of sample inputs.

Answer (score 4):

```
[
   {url: 'http://google.com/',
    name: 'google',
    inputs: [
        { name: 'search-term', type: 'string', value: 'javascript' },
        { name: 'region', type: 'country-code', value: 'IN' }
    ]
   },
   {url: 'http://yahoo.com/',
    name: 'yahoo',
    inputs: [
        { name: 'search-term', type: 'string', value: 'javascript' },
        { name: 'region', type: 'country-code', value: 'US' }
    ]
   }
]
```

there you go.

on a related note, [JSON](http://www.json.org/) might be worth looking at once. Though I must say, the above is not json, only json-like.

Comment: well, thanks, so is this right ???   `code` var test =
  [
   {url: 'http://google.com/',
    name: 'google',
    inputs: [
        { name: 'search-term', type: 'string', value: 'javascript' },
        { name: 'region', type: 'country-code', value: 'IN' }
    ]
   },
   {url: 'http://yahoo.com/',
    name: 'yahoo',
    inputs: [
        { name: 'search-term', type: 'string', value: 'javascript' },
        { name: 'region', type: 'country-code', value: 'US' }
    ]
   }
]`code`

Comment: @shail Close. Your semicolons after your urls will break your code. You only need a comma in those places.

Answer (score 1):

This would be tricky in a strongly typed language like Java or C#, but it's pretty easy in JavaScript.

Since JavaScript doesn't have strong typing for array values and variables, you can just create an array of object literals. Each object would contain the properties you specified. There's no need to specify the `string` type on each property--JavaScript will infer that for you.

While this is really easy to do, the drawback is that you're not going to get any type checking, so some code could inadvertently stick an object into one of your string fields and JavaScript won't stop it.

So just beware of the advantages and disadvantages of JavaScript's flexibility, and make sure you're doing server-side sanity checks on your data.

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = 
[
    {
        url: "http://...",
        name: "FOO",
        inputs: [
            {
                name: "Input1",
                type: "LeTypeh"
                value: "Levalueh"
            },
            {
                name: "Input2 (Foo)",
                type: "LeType2a",
                value: "Levalue2j"
            }
            // ... (insert as many comma separated inputs as you need in the foo item
    },
    {
        url: "http://...",
        name: "BAR",
        inputs: [
            {
                name: "Input1",
                type: "LeTypeh"
                value: "Levalueh"
            },
            {
                name: "Input2 (Bar)",
                type: "LeType2a",
                value: "Levalue2j"
            }
            // ... (insert as many comma separated inputs as you need in the bar item here
    }
    //... (insert as many comma separated items as you need in the array here
]
```